# How to update saved items AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

[ScreenShot of error when trying mergeItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhBd0.png) Im trying to save some recent searches that every user does in my app I setItem using Asyncstorage but this deletes the previous searches and mergeItem does not seem to work here and recommendations?

```
_storeSearches = async (numberToSave) => {
try {
 await AsyncStorage.mergeItem('SNUMBER', numberToSave);
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
}
};

_retrievePhoneNumberSearches = async () => {
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.setItem('SNUMBER');
  if (value !== null) {
    return JSON.parse(value);
  }
  return [];
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
};
```

The goal here is to have a list of the recent searches that the user did and update the list has he searches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `mergeItem` only works on objects using a `key/value` pair, and it seems that you are wanting to use it for updating an array.

> Merges an existing key value with an input value, assuming both values
>   are stringified JSON.

So doing something like this updates the original object stored.

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('person', JSON.stringify({age: 36 }));
await AsyncStorage.mergeItem('person', JSON.stringify({name: 'Chris'}))
let person = await AsyncStorage.getItem('person')
```

If we look at the `person` variable it would be the object `{age: 36, name: 'Chris'}`

But as you are trying to update an array I don't think it will work. However, there is a convoluted way that you could make AsyncStorage work for you.

1. First set an empty array
2. Check to see if there is a value for `SNUMBER`
3. If there is update the array with the saved array
4. Push the `numberToSave` into the array
5. Save the array to AsyncStorage (remembering to stringify)

Here is the code

```
_storeSearches = async (numberToSave) => {
  let numberArray = [];
  try {
    let storedNumbers = await AsyncStorage.getItem('SNUMBER');
    if (storedNumbers !== null) {
      numberArray = JSON.parse(storedNumbers); // you could do some additional checks to make sure it is an array
    }
    numberArray.push(numberToSave)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('SNUMBER', JSON.stringify(numberArray));
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
```

It is convoluted and not ideal but it should work.

Comment: Hi Thanks! 
but the catch log's the following error 
    `numberArray.push is not a function. (In 'numberArray.push(numberToSave)', 'numberArray.push' is undefined)
* screens/HomeScreen.js:121:23 in _callee4$`

Comment: That's probably because the value you stored for `SNUMBER` previously was not an array. You need to overwrite what you have stored for that value or delete the app from your device and re-install. Also I did say you should do some additional checks to make sure it is an array. Alternatively you could just change the key name that you are saving it in AsyncStorage as

Comment: Thanks you! changing the name SNUMBER worked just fine